# iOs Cloning Application using wildcard ApppleId

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-id

I have create a iOs application in Xcode , now i want to clone this with logo change and App name Change.
so which one is better ,

from **"Explicit App ID"** or **"Wildcard App ID"**.
can any one help me to choose.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1713/_index.html

First of all you can't deploy your application with "**Wildcard App ID**".
It's used only for development, and it's related to Provisioning Profile, not AppID.
So you should use 2 "**Explicit App ID**" for both applications.

Anyway your application will be rejected by Apple
*2.20 Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar Apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program*
So have a look to [Appstore Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)